# Acessar dispositivos periféricos pelo browser

Tags: c#, webforms, navegador-de-internet

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web para controle financeiro é preciso imprimir notas fiscais em impressora térmica/fiscal.

Seria possível integrar esse dispositivo pelo browser ou serei obrigado a desenvolver uma aplicação desktop para isso?

Answer (score 3):

Dependendo da sua infraestrutura, você pode fazer a sua aplicação Web interagir diretamente com a sua impressora fiscal a partir do seu servidor. Para isso é necessário que este tenha acesso à impressora.

Desta maneira você elimina configurações individuais para cada máquina que irá utilizar sua aplicação; apenas seu servidor precisará possuir o driver para o dispositivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O namespace [`System.Drawing.Printing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing(v=vs.110).aspx) possui classes que podem atender à sua necessidade. Segue [um exemplo na MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

É possível, basta definir um layout de impressão e enviar o documento como qualquer outro, para a impressora do equipamento, seja térmica ou não, quem gerencia a impressora é a máquina, você apenas vai gerar uma espécie de relatório, aonde vai estar diagramado no formato da nota que você utiliza.